# How to solve a error message by uploading a dataset as read.csv()

Tags: r, read.csv

I tried to upload a dataset in R to get a scatterplot. However, it came out below error message even when I transferred the dataset from xlsx to csv format. It's so strange, and it works fine with other dataset in CSV format. Appreciate any feedback for below.

[image]

I have tried to rename the column name to different names, but it still didn't work.